# How to install Evernote SDK for Python

Tags: evernote

I'm trying to get started with the Evernote SDK for python. I'm following the quick-start guide here:
https://dev.evernote.com/doc/start/python.php

I'm running into 2 errors:
1. When I try the first command "python setup.py install" I get this error message:

File "setup.py", line 22
    packages=find_packages('lib',exclude=["*.thrift", "*.thrift.*", "thrift.*", "thrift"]),
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated

2. When I try "pip install evernote" I get:

Collecting evernote
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement evernote (from versions: )
  No matching distribution found for evernote

Any help would be much appreciated. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Update:

It turns out I was using an old version of pip, which was causing the problem. I had to use "sudo -H pip uninstall pip" and then reinstall the latest version for some reason.

"pip install evernote" worked after that.